# Pgfplots: fill between let the axis options to be neglected

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

In the following example, the axis lines should be `yellow` and `ultra thick`, but using the `fill between` instruction let the axis options to be neglected:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
  yellow, ultra thick   % <--- neglected
]
\addplot+ [name path=sup] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\addplot+ [name path=inf] coordinates{(0,0) (1,0)};
\addplot [blue!50] fill between [of=sup and inf]; % <--- this is the problem
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add this to the preamble: `\pgfplotsset{axis line style={yellow, ultra thick}}`

Comment: @Ross, could you explain the reason for this odd behavior? I think that such an instruction should have no reason to change the general options for the axis environment.

Comment: Using `axis line style` applies the axis formatting after the plot is drawn (see section 4.9 of `pgfplots` manual). From section 5.7 of the manual: "as soon as `pgfplots` encounters a fill between
plot, it will activate layered graphics. The filled path will be placed on layer pre main which is between the main layer and the background layer". That's about as much as I know. Maybe someone can explain better.

Comment: Doesn't happen to me (I mean, I have yellow ultra thick axis lines with your code, although ticks are in black).

Comment: I think this is a bug already reported [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/138/).

Comment: As far as I can tell: `yellow` will go into `every axis`. And for some reason `every axis` behaves differently when `set layers` is on. Possible related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287975/