# pgfplots: How to set “axis on top” only for abscissa and ordinate, but not for grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes, axis, layers

I try to format a `ybar` diagram nicely.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar                    = 1.5mm,
    ymin                    = 0,
    ymax                    = 300,
%   set layers              = true,
%   axis on top             = true,
    symbolic x coords       = {Blub, Blab, Blop},
    ymajorgrids             = true,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align = {vertical},
    nodes near coords style = {text=black},
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
    ]
    \addplot[fill=red, draw=red] coordinates {(Blab,180) (Blop,180) (Blub,180)};%
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Screenshot of the issue:**

[image: Screenshot of the issue 1]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, the `ybars` are positioned in a visibility layer above the abscisse, therefore the abscisse is partly hidden by `ybars`. Well, I could easily activate `set layers = true` as well as `axis on top = true`, but in this case also the grid will be moved to the foreground layer while then hiding the `node label texts`. However, the `node label texts` should remain in the foreground above the grid lines (like seen here):

[image: Screenshot of the issue 2]

Therefore it is not possible to just activate the upper commands.

Is there an option available to only put abscisse (x-axis) and ordinate (y-axis) to the foreground layer of visibility while keeping the grids in the background?

The user [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483603/78784) has posted an approach on how to keep the `node text labels` in the foreground, even when setting `set layers = true` and `axis on top = true`. Would it be possible to do something similar for abscisse and ordinate only while keeping grid in background?

Comment: Into your code there is an error: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/nodes near coords style', to which you passed 'text=black', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. [        \end{axis}]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! In my case this MWE works completely fine? Hmm, now I am wondering...

Comment: @Sebastiano: I have updated my request. Now you can see it better I hope. :-)

Comment: Ah :-). I think I get it. You want it just above, right? That is, you want to see the x-axis and above it just a little bit you want to see the red bar.

Comment: Haha. :-) I don't want to move/shift the `x-axis` or the plot actually. I just want to put the abscisse into a visibility layer above the plot, so the plot can not hide the `x-axis` anymore. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano: I hope one can understand what I mean now. :-) I have just updated my request once again. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't help you. Many times I think I understand, but I don't.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Ah, absolutely no worries! This is a great community - I really appreciate your help even for your approach to help! :-)

Comment: I'm doing what I can even though I'm with bronchitis right now. :-( +1 for all.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288065/31034

Comment: @ferahfeza: Indeed! Thanks a lot, now it is working! :-)

Comment: @Dave, your welcome.