# Place tick scale label on top of plot contents

Tags: labels, groupplots, ticks, scale, layers

I came up with a pretty neat way to avoid overlap between tick scale labels and axis bounds for stacked plots by moving the tick scale labels into the axis windows, but unfortunately the lines are drawn on top of them. I tried fiddling around with the information in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350458), but got nowhere.

Whether it be by forcing the tick scale label to be drawn last or some other means, how can I ensure that the tick scale label is not occluded by anything?

MWE:
[image]

```latex
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{tab10_1}{rgb}{0.1216, 0.4667, 0.7059}
\definecolor{tab10_2}{rgb}{1.0, 0.498, 0.0549}
\definecolor{tab10_3}{rgb}{0.1725, 0.6275, 0.1725}
\definecolor{tab10_4}{rgb}{0.8392, 0.1529, 0.1569}
\definecolor{tab10_5}{rgb}{0.5804, 0.4039, 0.7412}
\definecolor{tab10_6}{rgb}{0.549, 0.3373, 0.2941}
\definecolor{tab10_7}{rgb}{0.8902, 0.4667, 0.7608}
\definecolor{tab10_8}{rgb}{0.498, 0.498, 0.498}
\definecolor{tab10_9}{rgb}{0.7373, 0.7412, 0.1333}
\definecolor{tab10_10}{rgb}{0.0902, 0.7451, 0.8118}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{tab10}{
    {tab10_1},
    {tab10_2},
    {tab10_3},
    {tab10_4},
    {tab10_5},
    {tab10_6},
    {tab10_7},
    {tab10_8},
    {tab10_9},
    {tab10_10}
}

\newlength{\figureheight}
\newlength{\figurewidth}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style = {
        line join = round,
        line cap = round,
        cycle list name = tab10,
        grid = major,
        grid style = {
            dashed,
            color = black!50
        },
    },
    every y tick scale label/.style={
        % This looks great -- until the line gets drawn on top!
        at = {(0, 1)},
        xshift = 0pt,
        anchor = north west,
        outer sep = 0pt,
        inner sep = 0.2em,
        fill = white,
        draw = black
    },
    ytick scale label code/.code={
        % The default code. Maybe I could tweak this to my needs somehow?
        $\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/tick scale binop} 10^{#1}$
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetlength{\figureheight}{4.5cm}
\pgfmathsetlength{\figurewidth}{12cm}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size={1 by 2},
    vertical sep={\figureheight/15}},
    height={\figureheight},
    width={\figurewidth}, 
    xtick={0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
]
    \nextgroupplot[
        ylabel={$\bm{x}$ (n.d.)},
        legend columns={-1},
        legend pos={north east},
        legend entries={$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$},
        xticklabel={\empty},
        title={Labels Occluded By Lines}
    ]
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  1.0e-10  \\
            1.0  1.0e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  0.0e-10  \\
            1.0  0.0e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  0.5e-10  \\
            1.0  0.5e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \nextgroupplot[
        ylabel={$\bm{x}^\prime$ (n.d.)},
        legend columns={-1},
        legend pos={north east},
        legend entries={{$x^\prime_1$, $x^\prime_2$, $x^\prime_3$}},
        xlabel={Common abscissa axis}
    ]
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  1.0e-10  \\
            1.0  1.0e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  0.0e-10  \\
            1.0  0.0e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  0.5e-10  \\
            1.0  0.5e-10  \\
        }
        ;
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the option `axis on top` if you don't mind that the grid appears above the plot.

```tex
\pgfplotsset{axis on top}
```

If you want the grid below the curves and the axis label above, you should use layers to organise precisely the different elements (see `pgfplots` manual, section 4.27, or [Tikz axis border on top, grids below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266650/316068)). It seems that the y tick scale label is in the `main` layer. Define de `plot` layer, below the `main` one:

```tex
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/layers/my layers/.define layer set={
      axis background,
      axis grid,
      axis ticks,
      pre main,
      plot,
      main,
      axis lines,
      axis tick labels,
      axis descriptions,
      axis foreground
    }{/pgfplots/layers/standard},
    set layers=my layers,
}
```

and draw the curves on that layer, with:

```tex
 every axis plot/.style={on layer=plots}
```

Full code:

```tex
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{tab10_1}{rgb}{0.1216, 0.4667, 0.7059}
\definecolor{tab10_2}{rgb}{1.0, 0.498, 0.0549}
\definecolor{tab10_3}{rgb}{0.1725, 0.6275, 0.1725}
\definecolor{tab10_4}{rgb}{0.8392, 0.1529, 0.1569}
\definecolor{tab10_5}{rgb}{0.5804, 0.4039, 0.7412}
\definecolor{tab10_6}{rgb}{0.549, 0.3373, 0.2941}
\definecolor{tab10_7}{rgb}{0.8902, 0.4667, 0.7608}
\definecolor{tab10_8}{rgb}{0.498, 0.498, 0.498}
\definecolor{tab10_9}{rgb}{0.7373, 0.7412, 0.1333}
\definecolor{tab10_10}{rgb}{0.0902, 0.7451, 0.8118}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{tab10}{
    {tab10_1},
    {tab10_2},
    {tab10_3},
    {tab10_4},
    {tab10_5},
    {tab10_6},
    {tab10_7},
    {tab10_8},
    {tab10_9},
    {tab10_10}
}

\newlength{\figureheight}
\newlength{\figurewidth}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style = {
        line join = round,
        line cap = round,
        cycle list name = tab10,
        grid = major,
        grid style = {
            dashed,
            color = black!50
        },
    },
    every y tick scale label/.style={
        % This looks great -- until the line gets drawn on top!
        at = {(0, 1)},
        xshift = 0pt,
        anchor = north west,
        outer sep = 0pt,
        inner sep = 0.2em,
        fill = white,
        draw = black
    },
    ytick scale label code/.code={
        % The default code. Maybe I could tweak this to my needs somehow?
        $\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/tick scale binop} 10^{#1}$
    },
    /pgfplots/layers/my layers/.define layer set={
      axis background,
      axis grid,
      axis ticks,
      pre main,
      plots,
      main,
      axis lines,
      axis tick labels,
      axis descriptions,
      axis foreground
    }{/pgfplots/layers/standard},
    set layers=my layers,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetlength{\figureheight}{4.5cm}
\pgfmathsetlength{\figurewidth}{12cm}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size={1 by 2},
    vertical sep={\figureheight/15}},
    height={\figureheight},
    width={\figurewidth},
    xtick={0.0, 0.5, 1.0},
    every axis plot/.style={on layer=plots}
]
    \nextgroupplot[
        ylabel={$\bm{x}$ (n.d.)},
        legend columns={-1},
        legend pos={north east},
        legend entries={$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$},
        xticklabel={\empty},
        title={Labels Occluded By Lines},
    ]
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  1.0e-10  \\
            1.0  1.0e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  0.0e-10  \\
            1.0  0.0e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  0.5e-10  \\
            1.0  0.5e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \nextgroupplot[
        ylabel={$\bm{x}^\prime$ (n.d.)},
        legend columns={-1},
        legend pos={north east},
        legend entries={{$x^\prime_1$, $x^\prime_2$, $x^\prime_3$}},
        xlabel={Common abscissa axis}
    ]
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  1.0e-10  \\
            1.0  1.0e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  0.0e-10  \\
            1.0  0.0e-10  \\
        }
        ;
    \addplot+[no markers, very thick]
        table[row sep={\\}]
        {
            x  y  \\
            0.0  0.5e-10  \\
            1.0  0.5e-10  \\
        }
        ;
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph with label above plot]